# how to add a trailing letter to words in a row of sentence if a particular word is found

Tags: r, string

here is my sample data

```
x <-  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
y <- c("apple, red, orange, vintage, classic", "pear, plums, oranges/clementines", "mangos, red, guava, pear", "grapes, strawberry, blackberry", "raspberry, red, blue/green")

mydata <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to create a new column using column y.  For each row of data in column y, which has the word “red”, all the word gets a trailing letter “r”, so row1 of the new column “z” would be "appler, redr, oranger, vintager, classicr”.  The rows that do not contain the word “red” remain as is.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the code you tried? It would be helpful to have a clearer picture of what you are doing.

Comment: how do you handle `oranges/clementines`?

Comment: I am trying to differentiate between say oranges in two different lines, based on information contained within the line.  In my case "oranges/clementines" would be considered as a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using `strsplit`, (`mydata` read with `stringsAsfactors = FALSE`)

```
v1 <- grepl('red', mydata$y) #Identify rows with "red"

mydata$y[v1] <- sapply(strsplit(mydata$y[v1], ', '), function(i) toString(paste0(i, 'r')))                                                                

mydata
#  x                                         y
#1 1 appler, redr, oranger, vintager, classicr
#2 2          pear, plums, oranges/clementines
#3 3              mangosr, redr, guavar, pearr
#4 4            grapes, strawberry, blackberry
#5 5             raspberryr, redr, blue/greenr
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very odd transformation but you can use regular expressions both to find "red" and add "r"s.

```
mydata <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

match.rows <- grep("\\bred\\b", mydata$y)

mydata$y[match.rows] <- gsub("(\\w)(?=(,|$))","\\1r", mydata$y[match.rows], perl=T)
```

which results in

```
mydata
#   x                                         y
# 1 1 appler, redr, oranger, vintager, classicr
# 2 2          pear, plums, oranges/clementines
# 3 3              mangosr, redr, guavar, pearr
# 4 4            grapes, strawberry, blackberry
# 5 5             raspberryr, redr, blue/greenr
```